# Outlier removal using the minimal cost function hiding the second image

Tags: c#, algorithm, image, outliers

**Update**

After receiving no response for the question I posted yesterday, I did my own research on how to complete the Matrix entries for Matrix A and Matrix B so that my method would calculate and return a Transformation that would align a certain image B to A, I found a research paper from this [site](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317721879_Image_Registration_Based_on_a_Minimized_Cost_Function_and_SURF_Algorithm) that has the derives for the matrix entries listed. I directly substituted the expressions in my Matrix entries loop but now the second image has removed the outliers slightly but its on top of image A, the updated code is listed below...

```
 class ICPTransformation
    {

        public static Transformation ComputeTransformation(List<Point> shp1, List<Point> shp2) {
//create a new 4 by 4 Matrix A for computing the transformation
            PCALib.Matrix A = new PCALib.Matrix(4,4);
//create a new 4 by 1 Matrix for computing the transformation
            PCALib.Matrix B = new PCALib.Matrix(4, 1);
            //iterate through the points stored in the first shape
            for(int i = 0; i < shp1.Count; i++)
            {
                A[0,0] +=2*shp2[i].X*shp2[i].X+2*shp2[i].Y*shp2[i].Y;
                //completing the remaining entries for matrix A
                //it is important to note that matrix A is 4 by 4
                A[0, 1] += 0;
                A[0, 2] += 2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[0, 3] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[1, 0] += 0;
                A[1, 1] += 2 * shp2[i].Y * shp2[i].Y+2*shp2[i].X*shp2[i].X;
                A[1, 2] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[1, 3] += -2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[2, 0] += 2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[2, 1] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[2, 2] += 2;
                A[2, 3] += 0;
                A[3, 0] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[3, 1] += -2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[3, 2] += 0;
                A[3, 3] += -2;
                //completing the remaining entries for matrix B
                //the dimensions of Matrix B is 4 by one
                B[0, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X * shp2[i].X + 2 * shp1[i].Y * shp2[i].Y;
                B[1, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X * shp2[i].Y - 2 * shp2[i].X * shp1[i].Y;
                B[2, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X;
                B[3, 0] += -2 * shp1[i].Y;


            }
}
```

Can anyone help me remove this anomaly from my code, I suspect its the Matrix entries for either `Matrix A` or `Matrix B`

**Complete Program Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PCALib;

namespace OutlierRemoval
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //declare the lists that will hold the points
        List<Point> Shape1 = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> Shape2 = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> Shape2Transformed = new List<Point>();
        //initialize a panel that will hold the shapes
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //ADD THE PANEL TO THE FORM\
            //disable the second button until the first images has been initialized
            button2.Enabled = false;
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Shape1.Clear();
            Shape2.Clear();
            Point p1a = new Point(20, 30);
            Point p2a = new Point(120,50);
            Point p3a = new Point(160,80);
            Point p4a = new Point(180, 300);
            Point p5a = new Point(100,220);
            Point p6a = new Point(50, 280);
            Point p7a = new Point(20, 140);
            //Hold the Points in an array
            Point[] mypoints = new Point[] {p1a,p2a,p3a,p4a,p5a,p6a,p7a};
            //add the points to the List with one call
            Shape1.AddRange(mypoints);
            //add the points to Shape2
            //define a transformation that will map the shapes 
            //to new shape2
            Transformation t2 = new Transformation();
            t2.A = 1.05;t2.B = 0.05;t2.T1 = 15;t2.T2 = 22;
            Shape2 = ApplyTransformation(t2, Shape1);
            Shape2[2] = new Point(Shape2[2].X + 10, Shape2[2].Y + 3);//change a point
            //add outliers to both shapes
            Point ptOutlier1 = new Point(200, 300);
            Shape1.Add(ptOutlier1);
            Point ptOutlier2 = new Point(270, 160);
            Shape2.Add(ptOutlier2);
            //define the drawing pens with a color of your liking
            Pen pBlue = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);
            Pen pRED = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1);
            Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
           // g.DrawLines(pBlue, mypoints);
           // g.DrawLine(pBlue, Shape1[0], Shape1[Shape1.Count - 1]);
            //g.DrawLine(pBlue, Shape1[Shape1.Count - 1], Shape1[Shape1.Count - 2]);
            
           DisplayShape(Shape1, pBlue, g);
           DisplayShape(Shape2, pRED, g);
            //now button two can be cklicked
            button2.Enabled = true;
            
            
        }
        List<Point> ApplyTransformation(Transformation x,List<Point> shape) {
            List<Point> Tlist = new List<Point>();
            foreach (Point c in shape) {
                double xprime = x.A * c.X + x.B * c.Y + x.T1;
                double yprime = x.B * c.X * -1 + x.A * c.Y + x.T2;
                Point ptrans = new Point((int)xprime, (int)yprime);
                Tlist.Add(ptrans);
            }
            return Tlist;
        }
        void DisplayShape(List<Point> Shp,Pen pen, Graphics G)
        {
            Point? prevPoint = null;//nullable
            foreach(Point pt in Shp)
            {
                G.DrawEllipse(pen, new Rectangle(pt.X - 2, pt.Y - 2, 4, 4));
                if (prevPoint != null)
                {
                    G.DrawLine(pen, (Point)prevPoint, pt);
                    
                }
                prevPoint = pt;

            }
            G.DrawLine(pen, Shp[0], Shp[Shp.Count - 1]);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Transformation T = ICPTransformation.ComputeTransformation(Shape1, Shape2);
            MessageBox.Show("Cost = "+ICPTransformation.computeCost(Shape1,Shape2,T).ToString());
            List<Point> Shape2T = ApplyTransformation(T, Shape2);
            Pen pBlue = new Pen(Brushes.Blue,1);
            Pen pRed = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1);
            Graphics g = panel2.CreateGraphics();
 
           
            DisplayShape(Shape1,pBlue,g);
            DisplayShape(Shape2T, pRed, g);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           /* Transformation x = new Transformation();
            List<Point> mypoints = ApplyTransformation(x, Shape2);
            Graphics g = panel3.CreateGraphics();
            Pen mypen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);
            DisplayShape(mypoints, mypen, g);*/
        }
    }
    public class Transformation
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }
        public double T1 { get; set; }
        public double T2 { get; set; }
    }
    class ICPTransformation
    {

        public static Transformation ComputeTransformation(List<Point> shp1, List<Point> shp2) {
            PCALib.Matrix A = new PCALib.Matrix(4,4);
            PCALib.Matrix B = new PCALib.Matrix(4, 1);
            //iterate through the points stored in the first shape
            for(int i = 0; i < shp1.Count; i++)
            {
                A[0, 0] += 2 * shp2[i].X * shp2[i].X + 2 * shp2[i].Y * shp2[i].Y;
                //completing the remaining entries for matrix A
                //it is important to note that matrix A is 4 by 4
                A[0, 1] += 0;
                A[0, 2] += 2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[0, 3] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[1, 0] += 0;
                A[1, 1] += 2 * shp2[i].Y * shp2[i].Y + 2 * shp2[i].X * shp2[i].X;
                A[1, 2] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[1, 3] += -2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[2, 0] += 2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[2, 1] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[2, 2] += 2;
                A[2, 3] += 0;
                A[3, 0] += 2 * shp2[i].Y;
                A[3, 1] += -2 * shp2[i].X;
                A[3, 2] += 0;
                A[3, 3] += 2;
                //completing the remaining entries for matrix B
                //the dimensions of Matrix B is 4 by one
                B[0, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X * shp2[i].X + 2 * shp1[i].Y * shp2[i].Y;
                B[1, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X * shp2[i].Y - 2 * shp2[i].X * shp1[i].Y;
                B[2, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].X;
                B[3, 0] += 2 * shp1[i].Y;


            }
            //get the inverse of the Matrix A
            PCALib.Matrix Ainv =(PCALib.Matrix) A.Inverse;
            //multiply the two matrices to get the transformation
            PCALib.Matrix Res =(PCALib.Matrix) Ainv.Multiply(Ainv);
            Transformation T = new Transformation();
            T.A = Res[0, 0];
            T.B = Res[1, 0];
            T.T1 = Res[2, 0];
            T.T2 = Res[3, 0];
            return T;
            
        }
        public static double computeCost(List<Point> P1List, List<Point> P2List,Transformation T) {
            //initialize the cost to 0
            double cost = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < P1List.Count; i++) {
                double xprime = T.A * P2List[i].X + T.B * P2List[i].Y + T.T1;
                double yprime = -1 * T.B * P2List[i].X + T.A * P2List[i].Y + T.T2;
                cost += (P1List[i].X-xprime)*(P1List[i].X-xprime)+(P1List[i].Y-yprime)*(P1List[i].Y-yprime);
            }
            return cost;
        }
    }
    public class Tranformation
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }
        public double T1 { get; set; }
        public double T2 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Found a research paper that has the derives already, now it is just manipulating the co-ordinates in the loop

Comment: A[3,3] and B[3,0] haven the wrong sign when compared to the paper (equation 4) cited above. Is it intentional? If so, have you double checked that it doesn't introduce an error?

Comment: @S_Bersier, what values should  I use instead?

Comment: If you don't have any reason for this change of sign, then I would recommend to put: A[3, 3]  +=  +2;    and   B[3,0] +=  +2 * shp1[i].Y;    Just like in the paper.

Comment: @S_Bersier, Why the positive sign before the value, its the same as `A[3,3+=2`?

Comment: Of course. It was just to emphasize the sign. You can write: A[3, 3] += 2; and B[3,0] += 2 * shp1[i].Y;

Comment: Modified, still the same result

Comment: Following the conventions in the paper: RES is the vector (a,b,t1,t2) you're looking for. And I don't see how RES = A.Inverse * B can be the same if A has changed , unless y1 is always zero. It' doesn't make sense.  But  if you want, we can continue this discussion on chat. OK?

Comment: @S_Bersier, sure can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239183/discussion-between-kinyua-timothy-njiru-and-s-bersier).

Comment: On line 171: You have:"PCALib.Matrix Res =(PCALib.Matrix) Ainv.Multiply(Ainv);" But you should have: "PCALib.Matrix Res =(PCALib.Matrix) Ainv.Multiply(B);"

Comment: @Thanks man, that is the bug?

Comment: YOU GOT THE BOUNTY, How do I award?

Comment: @S_Bersier, God bless you man, you saved me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:-)
So, in order to recapitulate: There were signs problems on A and B.
And, on line 171, you have :

PCALib.Matrix Res =(PCALib.Matrix) Ainv.Multiply(Ainv);

Where you should have:
PCALib.Matrix Res =(PCALib.Matrix) Ainv.Multiply(B);

Just the kind of mistakes you can look for during hours and hours... :-)
Best regards,
Stéphane